# How find all the partition information for the oracle table

Tags: oracle

I have a partitioned table t that is partitioned on a column using list partition,

I want to query out all the partition and also its corresponding column values.

It is the same as in PLSQL Developer: when I view sql for this table, it shows all the partitions like:

```
  partition DATA_20180522 values (20180522)
    tablespace DMSCMDAT
    pctfree 10
    initrans 1
    maxtrans 255
    storage
    (
      initial 8M
      next 1M
      minextents 1
      maxextents unlimited
    )
```

I google searched,but I don't find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find information on partitions you can query the ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS
```

and for much of the other info on a table you can query ALL_TABLES:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_TABLES
```

If you want to recreate the source code for a table you need to write code. [A good place to start is the code in this question at asktom.oracle.com](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1464804639878).

Best of luck.

Comment: I am not sure what happens in my end， I could be able to query ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS and ALL_TABLES,but no data is queried out.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that you don't have access to the ALL_ views. You might try the `USER_TABLES` and `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS` views, but those won't help if the table you're interested in is in a different schema from the user you're logged in as. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! Looks I am in a different schema

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer suggested, you could look at USER|ALL|DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS. But if your goal is to get the DDL, then the [DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885) function is likely going to be loads easier. Use the SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM options to tailor the output to your liking.